# VBA to stop running nested macros in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on my spreadsheet that when clicked, triggers a series of nested subs. Example:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Macro1
    Macro2
    Macro3
    Macro4
    Macro5
    Macro6
End Sub
```

Because the time to run all these subroutines can be rather lengthy, and the user cannot do anything else in excel while it is running, I was wondering if there was a way to create a button that, when clicked, can halt the running of all these subs? I've seen recommendations of adding `DoEvent` to the code, however, I'm not sure where in my code to implement it.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DoEvents` statement will allow any lagging user input and handling of events.

### The Solution

What you probably want to do is overload the `OnKey` event handler and use it to set the value of a global variable. Next in your code above you need to verify if that variable is set. If it is abort execution. Be sure to add `DoEvents` statements in any moments in your code where you want this to run.

**Optionally**, w/o the `OnKey` handler, `DoEvents` will allow the user to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to stop the execution of your macro. But it will revert to debug mode and highlight the current executed row in your procedure. Not sure this is what you want however.

### Tip - what to do first

Having said that... what I personally think you should do **FIRST** is optimize your VBA code. I would assume there is probably a lot of room for improving the execution time of your procedure ([my tutorial](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/)).

Comment: You can also use `Application.EnableCancelKey` to handle the Esc key more gracefully with an error handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Macro to perform below steps/operation and call when you want to abort the other running macros:

**Step 1-- Menu bar -> Run -> Reset**

**Step 2-- Menu bar -> Run -> Break**